# Can't get Docker image after windows installation

Tags: docker, dns, docker-machine, docker-registry

I just installed docker on my **windows 10** server,

[Installation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) went fine but I can't seem to get images from central docker repo.

***those are my specs:***

```
c:\>docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Wed Jan 18 16:20:26 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Wed Jan 18 16:20:26 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

This is my test command:

```
c:\>docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: remote error: tls: access denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

This is what I get when running curl on that repo:

```
c:\>curl -k https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}
```

I guess that there is something to do with my company DNS/Network,

did anyone encounter this issue on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I replied to **@Falco Alexander** I got some PowerShell errors, But The proxy was already set in my env. variables.
What finally did the trick was to set the proxy inside the docker GUI:

[image]

[image]

And then restart the service.

Comment: this is the reason I don't like DfW, GUI and normal config isn't always consistent... :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your proxy env variables.

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY", "http://username:password@proxy:port/", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
Restart-Service docker
```

Check this for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon

And more common:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#http-proxy

Comment: I got some PowerShell errors, But The proxy was already set in my env. variables .